# Show result after space

Tags: c++

I have written small code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str = "hello world";

    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
            if(str[i] == ' ')
                      // WHAT?
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

How can I show result after space?

Example: "hello world"

Answer: "world"

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the exact behavior that you are looking for? And how the current code is failing you in that regard. Your question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [*`std::string::substr`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr), after finding the location of space using [*`std::string::find`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

```
string str = "hello world";
auto n = str.find(" ");     // std::string::size_type n =
if (n != std::string::npos ) 
{
    std::cout << str.substr( n+1 );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str = "hello world";

    size_t len = str.size();
    size_t space;
    if ((space = str.find(' ')) != string::npos) {
        cout << str.substr(space + 1, len-space) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`npos` is returned by `find()` method when there is no (in this example) space character in string. If it was found, then `substr()` method is used in order to take the part of string after space.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
// your code goes here
string str = "hello world";
cout << str.substr( str.find(' ') + 1, string::npos );
return 0;
}
```

I use the `std::string` methods `find()` and `substr()`.

`find()` returns the location/position of occurrence of space (' '), which is then passed to `substr()` which returns the `string` starting at that position until the end.

If you notice the fist parameter to `substr()`, it is 1 more than what is returned by `find()`. This is because you want to print whatever comes **after** the space, and which must not include space itself! Hence adding 1 to point to the character after the space.